# expandableListView in Listview dynamically android

Tags: android

I have to display like this in my application can you please suggest some code for this through web services(dynamically):-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) tutorial might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Fragments. Go through this tutorial : [Complete Fragment Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: noam not asking about fragment am asking about expandable list view

Comment: Check this too: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/android-simple-expandable-listview.html

Comment: but that is in static am getting in static way but am not getting in dynamically  pls tel me in brief.